# Is there a lockout feature in Azure AD MFA?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I am using AzureAD. And I am implementing MFA.
I know that if the user ID and password login fails a certain number of times, it locks me out.
However, repeated failures in MFA after passing user ID and password authentication will not lock out the user.
Repeated failures on the MFA screen will return you to the initial login screen.
Is this a specification?
If it is possible to lock out even with MFA, please let me know how.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, lockout feature is **available** in Azure AD MFA. Please note that this feature is applied **only** when the users use **`PIN code`** for the MFA prompt.

In order to configure this feature, you need **administrator** role.

Based on the **`number of failure trials`** you provided in settings, account lockout happens respectively.

To configure this feature, please follow below steps:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Security -> Multifactor authentication -> Account lockout***

[image]

In the above fields, enter the number based on your requirement and Save.

Like this, you can configure lockout feature in Azure AD MFA.

> Make sure to use **`PIN`** for MFA authentication.

Complete credits to below ***Microsoft Doc***:

[**Configure Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings#account-lockout)